# how to set username password for a windows application from a applet

Tags: c#, windows, applet

I'm trying to launch a windows application(application written using C#) from a applet.

the web application is written in javascript, so i'm using a applet to call the windows application.

I have already did the launching part of the application using the applet.

but the windows application which is not written by me, need a username and password to login.

i can get those two values from inside the web application. via a database query.

Now i need to set the username and password for that windows application, without any user interaction and launch the application from inside the web appliaction.

please give me instructions how to perform this action.

--
Best Regards,
Rangana

Comment: What are you calling an _applet_?

Comment: If you read your question again, do you really think you're providing us with enough detail?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience caused, i hope now the question is clear?

Comment: Can you pass the credentials via command line? Does the application open a dialog where the user needs to enter the credentials? What are your options as to how you can feed the credentials into the application?

Comment: application open a dialog where the user needs to enter the credentials, the user have to type in the username and the password. user have a single account for all these applications. i can get the username and the password from inside the web application.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass it on command line. While launching the application use following command line to launch your application

```
app.exe user=??? password=???
```

and read these parameters in your program

Comment: Do you really have enough detail to be able to write an answer? Are you sure that the OP doesn't want to run the application under a different user account (Impersonation)?

Comment: i can assure you that this is not impersonation. this is adding standalone application launching capability from a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Your windows program should be able to access the passed arguments from command line

```
call program.exe username password
```

example

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

               username = args[1]
               password = args[2]

              //validate

      }
 }
```